# The rank of block skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Suppose we have following speical block skew symmetric matrix
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & X_3 & -X_2\\
-X_3& 0& X_1\\
X_2 &-X_1 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $X_1,X_2,X_3\in R^{n \times n}$ and not invertible,**can we determine the rank of X via the combination of $X_1$,$X_2$ and $X_3$** like ${\rm rank}(X)$=${\rm rank}(X_1-X_3)$+${\rm rank}(X_2X_3)$?It seems difficuty to obtained $X$ by elementary transformation

Comment: @Moo it's difficulty if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is not invertible

Comment: I suspect we can show something like $\text{rank}(X) \le 2(\text{rank}(X_1)+\text{rank}(X_2)+\text{rank}(X_3))$, but I'm not sure if we can show more than that without additional assumptions on $X_1,X_2,X_3$.

Comment: When $X_1=X_2=X_3=0$ , $rk(X)=0$ . When $X_3 = 1_{n\times n} , X_2=X_1=0  ,rk(X)=2$ . So I don't think we have enough information to determine $rk(X)$ exactly .

Comment: @C.C Can we get the rank expression of combination of $X_1,X_2 $and $X_3$ by elementary transformation? Elementary transformation doesn't change the rank of the matrix

Comment: @JimmyK4542 thanks for your reply,I want a explicit expression

Comment: @Moo if all three are zero,the rank is 0,if never zero and invertible ,the rank is 2n

Comment: @Moo $X_1,X_2,X_3 \in R^{n \times n}$

Comment: Have you tried factorizing $X$ or the matrix $K$ that maps any vector in $R^{3n}$ to $ker(X)$ ? e.g with more assumptions , maybe 
$u\in R^{3n} \mapsto (s_1,s_2,s_3)^T , s_i \in ker(X_i) ,i=1,2,3  \mapsto y \in ker(X)$ . Maybe it's easier to find the rank of those factorizations ?